# NSDictionary allKeys is crashing my app? Because I can't use numeric keys?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have the following json string `["a","b"]` which I fetched from the url `http://mysite.com`.  Here's the code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSData *dataresult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataresult options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"logging:%@", [json allKeys]);
```

The last line of this code crashed my application with a SIGBRT error.   I noticed that I can't seem to access any elements in the NSDictionary with a numeric index as a key.

I just wnat to be able to do the PHP equivalent of:

```
echo $json[1]; //gives me a
```

I intend to load my json with more complex data objects, that are to be accessed via numeric keys.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an NSDictionary. You're retrieving NSArray and trying to ask NSArray to give you allKeys.